# If I want to run Nginx and Django, what's the best method?

Tags: python, django, apache, http, nginx

A couple of questions:

- Should I use FastCGI or uWSGI?
- Should I modify the nginx.conf file or the file in /site-enabled/default?
- What tutorial should I use?

Comment: I guess it's naive to hope that after 865 questions, you'd know not to ask three separate questions in the same post...

Comment: @Glenn All those questions seem like they're directed at the single task of running Django behind nginx. Don't give them a hard time for that.

Comment: @Paul: It's three questions asking for three different answers.  It's the fact that he has 865 questions that's bothersome--he's not new at this, and from seeing his questions over time, I'm pretty sure that he just doesn't care.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official Wiki is really helpful : http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/ServerArrangements / http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DjangoAndNginx